# C#, counting data blocks/pieces within a File Name(Mask). Example Smith_John_1234_06202019.zip

Tags: c#, file, filesystems, filenames

**Issue:**

I need a piece of code that will go through all files in a folder and locate broken file masks.

I basically want to go out a get a count from each data piece within each file mask and if the file mask does NOT return 4 data pieces (Last Name_First Name_Last4 SSN_Date of Hire), then I want to move that broken file into another folder.

**I only need help with:**

Code that will “count” all the data pieces separated by the underscores ( _ ). 


 I cannot just simply get a character count because obviously first and last names are unique. So I would imagine I will have to count each data piece.


**Summary:**

I’m building a program that will fix file mask names for .zip files. If these zip files do not match the below file mask(name) EXACTLY then they cannot be processed through our systems. 


They must have the 4 pieces of data listed in the name in the exact order. Each data piece is ALWAYS divided by an underscore ( _ ).


**File Mask Format:**
Last Name_First Name_Last4 SSN_Date of Hire

**Example:**
Smith_John_1234_06202019

Typically the issue I need to fix for is when the LAST 4 SSN is missing from the file mask, so the broken file mask will look like:
Smith_John__06202019

**the “1234” is missing from the file mask(name). HOWEVER, the underscore is still there.**

Comment: Please share what you have done so far, and ask for help with a specific problem you have.

Comment: @Derek, the community intended to help with the issue, but not writing codes instead of you. plz provide what you have done so far and probably we will have to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use Regex? This code below solve your problem.

```
string pattern = @"^[\w]*[_][\w]*[_][\d]{4}[_][\d]*[.]?[\w]*?$";
string input = "Smith_John_1234_06202019.zip";
Match m = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
if (m.Success)
    Console.WriteLine("OK");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Not OK");
```

Answer (score 0):

@Eric's answer is almost correct. @Derek wrote, that *typical* issue is with SSN number missing, but probably the input is wrong if any of the *data piece* is missing or invalid. So the change is to use *+* insted of *** in regex (and I assume that all files will be `.zip`).

```cs
if (Regex.IsMatch(fileNameWithExtension, @"^\w+_\w+_\d{4}_\d{8}\.zip$"))
{
    // OK
}
else
{
    // Not OK.
}
```